# Yii2 REST API not working properly

Tags: php, rest, yii2, swagger

I am creating an API for get user by YII2 user api by user id. If I pass user id then it is working good but If I pass string then I get below error.

```
<pre>An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\InvalidParamException: Response content must not be an array. in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:1020
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(313): yii\web\Response-&gt;prepare()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(128): yii\web\Response-&gt;send()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler-&gt;renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request: categories/wewqewqe in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:127
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller-&gt;runAction(&#039;wewqewqe&#039;, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(102): yii\base\Module-&gt;runAction(&#039;categories/wewq...&#039;, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application-&gt;handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/index.php(16): yii\base\Application-&gt;run()
#4 {main}

Next yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Page not found. in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:114
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application-&gt;handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/index.php(16): yii\base\Application-&gt;run()
#2 {main}</pre>
```

I am using `swagger` for executing APIs and Endpoint of the API is

```
users/{id}
```

Work fine when enter

```
/users/1
```

Get error when

```
/users/asdf
```

**Web.php**

```
'users/<id:\d+>' => 'users/',
```

Comment: Show your routing URL?

Comment: please check update question.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently faced same issue and it has been solved by the change in routing in web.php in config folder.

Change your url 
`users/<id>` instead of `users/<id:\d+>.`